# How to take screenshot of menu?

Tags: linux

How do I take a screenshot when e.g. the wrench menu in Chrome is open?

Or perhaps the File menu in Firefox?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have the option to capture the entire screen or the active window.

**Entire screen**

Install a tool for making screenshots, such as `scrot`, `gnome-screenshot` or ImageMagick, which provides `import`. Then run it with a delay from terminal, using one of these commands:

```
$ sleep 5; import -window root menu.png

$ scrot -cd 5 menu.png

$ gnome-screenshot -d 5
```

After running it, quickly open the menu and wait.

**Active window**

Both gnome-screenshot and scrot support taking a screenshot of the active window:

```
$ gnome-screenshot -wd 5

$ scrot -ucd 5 menu.png
```

Note that overlapping menus won't be compensated for but rather cut off:
[image]

Comment: When I tried the `import` I got a screenshot of another desktop (using Gnome 3), but the others most certainly worked perfect!

Comment: `scrot -cd 5` will take a screenshot in 5... 4... 3...

Comment: `gnome-screenshot -d 5` will have 5 second delay.  Add `-w` to only capture the active window, not the whole desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Capturing menus in open applications is what Shutter screenshot tool is designed to do (in Shutter's preferences, you can set it to take a screenshot after a few seconds, during which you can open the menu). Shutter can capture menus in their parent windows in any application, overlays, etc. as well as being able to capture everything that other screenshot tools can capture including entire screen, active window, selected area and webpage. Shutter is available in the repositories of most popular Linux distributions. In Debian-based distributions Shutter can be installed with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

The shutter .deb has been discontinued in Ubuntu 20.04. It is still available as a snap package and can be installed by running `sudo snap install shutter`, but Shutter's grab a screenshot of the current window plus one of its menus feature no longer works in the Shutter snap package. Fortunately the default "Screenshot" app in Ubuntu 20.04 has the capability of taking screenshots of menus that Shutter used to have in Ubuntu 18.04. To capture a screenshot of a window together with one of its menus, take a full screen screenshot and then crop it down from a full screen screenshot to a single window in an image editor. The Screenshot app can also grab a screenshot of the current window of a GTK app plus one of its menus.

Comment: `E: Package 'shutter' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @AhmadAlMughrabi I replied to your comment by updating my answer to the latest Ubuntu release.

Comment: Brilliant! Shutter is the way to go. It even allows editing the images within Shutter itself, so there's no need of opening Gimp to crop the image etc. More here: https://shutter-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

Click on the menu that you would like to take a screenshot.

Then click "Print Screen" button (or the Fn+Print Screen) on the keyboard. Depending upon the version of linux open Tuxpaint (I assume using Debian), and paste the image.

This will actually save the entire screen. You may crop the extra areas now and save it in desired format.

This is one of the simplest ways that I use for snapshots...

Comment: At least in GNOME 3, the menu loses focus and closes when Print Screen is pressed. (Seems to be a bug, though.)